# Fetch whole blog archive with RSS

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way in WordPress or a script to fetch ALL blog posts with the following from a blog through RSS?

```
title
text
images
categories
```

I've found some RSS plugins but they only get the recent 10 posts.

Edit: A plugin that could parse OTHER blogs RSS feed with the WHOLE archive, not just the recent 10 posts.

Answer (score 0):

- [RSS Feed Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpfeedforcustomposttype/)
- [Custom RSS Feeds by Envintus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-feeds/)

You'll need to customise your images

Comment: Not really what I was thinking about. I was asking for a plugin that could parse OTHER blogs RSS feed with the WHOLE archive, not just the recent 10 posts.